# Preventing the release of potential energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, potential-energy, string

Suppose I pull on the string of a bow without releasing it. My muscles are converting chemical energy (from food) to let the bow string stay at this position but this energy is not stored in the bow, I mean no matter what time I release the bow, it will produce the same effect.

My question is where did this energy go?
How it is conserved?

I thought about heat but if all the energy I’m spending is converted to heat how did I produce a constant force to prevent the string from releasing.

Comment: Have you taken the elastic energy of the bow string into account?

Comment: The chemical energy is converted into elastic potential energy (a bent bow behaves like a compressed spring).  When you release the bow, the elastic potential energy is converted into the kinetic energy of your arrow.

Comment: yea i did. after pulling the string the elastic energy of the bow string will become constant until release since the string won't be deformed anymore but my muscles are still using energy to prevent the string from releasing. That what is confusing me. I want to know to what form of energy that muscle enrgy is converted?

Comment: @DavideDalBosco I think the question focuses on the situation where the string is already stretched and you only use your muscles to hold it there.

Comment: What muscles do cannot be condensed into a simple statements like "converting chemical energy." It's similar to asking why do you get tired by holding a bucket of water for some minutes even though you aren't doing any work(on a macro scale). I suggest you read about how muscles are constantly expending energy to maintain a constant difference in ionic concentration to result in their contraction. It's a complex biological process. That's where the energy to exert a constant force is going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are confused about energy involving a human the problem is the human and the solution is to get rid of the human.

For example, in your case we can replace the human with a rigid bar to hold the bow and a spring to pull the string. The elastic PE in the spring can be used to pull the bow, and once it gets to the final equilibrium position it can hold it indefinitely without further decrease in elastic PE. There is energy required to pull the bow, there is not energy required to hold the bow in place.

The energy required by the human to hold the bow steady is purely due to inefficiencies in the human body and all of that energy is wasted as heat.

Comment: *the problem is the human and the solution is to get rid of the human.* All hail our robot overlords!

Comment: humans _are_ robots

Answer (score 1):

If a stick was used to hold the bow in the drawn position it would be doing no work. The archer's arms likewise do no work on the bow, but they must still apply a force. To apply the force requires the muscle cells to remain contracted, and they use more energy when they are contracted, producing heat as well as the lactic acid that causes a feeling of tiredness and eventually reduces the muscles' efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

In a static position, all the energy you use is converted to heat. To produce a constant force that does not move anything, you don't need to be expending energy. Place a book on a table; the table exerts a constant force on the book, but is not expending any energy. Only when the force is changing an object's velocity is when energy must be expended, because that energy is then converted into the object's kinetic energy.